# Combine two word from a MySQL database at random

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with nouns and adjectives for example:

```
id | type    | word  
-----------------------
1  | noun    | apple
2  | noun    | ball
3  | adj     | clammy
4  | noun    | keyboard
5  | adj     | bloody
```

ect...

I want to create one query what will grab 10 random adjectives and 10 random nouns and put them together.

Having trouble doing it, is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get 10 random elements per type with queries like this:

```
select word from YOUR_TABLE where type = 'noun' order by rand() limit 10;
select word from YOUR_TABLE where type = 'adj' order by rand() limit 10;
```

and then put them together in your PHP code, like so:

```
$phrases = array();

$adj_result  = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM words WHERE type = 'adj' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
$noun_result = mysql_query("SELECT word FROM words WHERE type = 'noun' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");

while($adj_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($adj_result)) {
  $noun_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($noun_result);
  $phrases[$adj_row['word']] = $noun_row['word'];
}

print_r($phrases);
```

Please note that this code is not very safe (it makes the assumption that the second query always yields as least as many results as the first), but you get the idea.

Edit: Here's a single SQL query that should do it:

```
select t1.word, t2.word 
from 
  ((select word from YOURTABLE where type = 'adj' order by rand()) as t1), 
  ((select word from YOURTABLE where type = 'noun' order by rand()) as t2) 
order by rand()
limit 10;
```

**EDIT: removed example**

Comment: I get an syntax error when running that query in MySQL, can you maybe show me the proper PHP? Not sure where to begin when creating a while loop or foreach with two queries. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the query you ran?

Comment: I just ran the above query in PHPmyadmin... Not sure how to create a loop for two queries

Comment: Did you replace YOUR_TABLE with your table name? And there's no easy way to concatenate this in one query, you may have to use a temporary table. But your question is tagged as PHP, so I assume you could just run two separate queries and do your combination of adjectives and nouns in PHP.

Comment: Also, these are two separate queries. I added semicolons to terminate them - that may have been your syntax error.

Comment: I dont mind two separate queries, but how would I just up a foreach or while loop to place the adjective and verbs together?

Comment: Try the pure SQL solution. It's probably not terribly efficient but it should give you the desired result.

Comment: The new query is close, but the first select 'adj' isn't random, has something to do with the first table being selected, because if you switch them, the nouns then are not random,

Comment: Why? Those are two independent subqueries, each on their own version of the table, no? It gives me random results from both tables on a test.

Comment: can you give me your mysql dump with table data and all?

Comment: No problem - is there a better place to do that than in a comment?

Comment: It's actually working, but I added another order by rand() to the outer query to avoid default sorting by the DB.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed work, but it is very database intensive. It takes over 9 seconds to run the query with a list of 2,000 words. Trying to find a way to do this faster.

Comment: Here is my word list database if you want to check a large database. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/127062/wordlist.sql.zip

Comment: Yup, the order by rand() wreaks havoc, even with indexing. I added a PHP example of the two query solution.

Comment: Very sorry but how would I output that array with a foreach, say into an <li> tag. Sorry but I have never seen an array like that.

Comment: It's called an associative array. You iterate through it with foreach($array as $key => $value). See the documentation for foeach: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php