# I want to create the simplest HTML code for random text generator

Tags: html, random, text

I took like one year or HTML and PHP programming but I don't think its enough for me to make this type of code, what should I look for or start with? I want it to simply print a random text (from a database I suppose) every time you open the page.

Comment: what does random text? maybe you meant a random number, as in the answer given below?

Comment: const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];

const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * months.length);
console.log(random, months[random]);

Answer (score -1):

`Math.random()` is built into Javascript.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

```js
document.write(Math.random());
```

PHP is like this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

You have many options for generating random numbers.

Answer (score -1):

[Combine two word from a MySQL database at random](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152765/combine-two-word-from-a-mysql-database-at-random)

That's a more complex sample, but you can reduce it to answer your need.
(Change the limit to 1 instead of 10 and instead of combining 2 words, just use one)